# SQLAlchemy Python 3 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I can't seem to install the newest version of SQLAlchemy in my Python 3. Similar questions asked on stackoverflow are all pre-2016 and talk about older distributions of Ubuntu, hence again this question.

### System

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 2.7.12 (default if I call python in terminal)
- Python 3.5.2

### Tried

If I follow the instructions from the documentation (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/intro.html#installation) `pip install SQLAlchemy`, it only installs itself into my Python 2.7 (`sqlalchemy.__version__`: 1.0.15).

`pip install python3-sqlalchemy` does not exist.

`sudo apt-get install python3-sqlalchemy` installs SQLAlchemy in Python3, but `sqlalchemy.__version__` gives 1.0.11

### Question

How do I get the latest version of SQLAlchemy into my Python3 directory, preferably without building from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip` is only for installing Python 2 packages.  To install a PyPI package for Python 3, you need to use `pip3`:

```
pip3 install SQLAlchemy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualenv:

```
pyvenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install sqlalchemy
```

Command `pyvenv` creates virtualenv based on python 3.x.